# arduino UNO light LEDs right-to-left and then reversed

Tags: arduino, led

I have 8 LEDs lined up on a breadboard, and I am trying to make them run from one end to the other and back, sorta like the lights on KITT (from night rider - hope that clarifies). the LEDs are all set up and correct and work.

I have set up my code like so:

```
int ledPins[]={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

void setup()
{
  for (int i =0; i <8; i++)
  {
    pinMode(ledPins[i],OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  for(int i =0; i<8; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],LOW);
  }

  for(int i =7; i<1; i--)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],LOW);
  }
}
```

but it doesn't cycle the LEDs from right to left and then back like I was aiming for.

**EDIT:** What it does do - is light the LEDs from right to left, but doesn't light them the opposite way (left to right). It just keeps going from right to left, right to left

I am using an Arduino UNO, and basing my circuit off the experimentation kit for Arudino [CIRC-02](http://ardx.org/src/circ/CIRC00-sheet-ADAF.pdf)

**EDIT #2:** So I have changed the for-loops to while loops:

```
int ledPins[]={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

void setup()
{
  for (int i =0; i <8; i++)
  {
    pinMode(ledPins[i],OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  int i = 0;
  while (i<7)
  {
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPins[i],HIGH);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(ledPins[i],LOW);
      i++;
    }
  }

  i = 7;
  while (i >0)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],LOW);
    i--;
  }
}
```

and it works as intended! 
**However, I am still interested in where my for-loop went wrong, if anybody has any ideas**

Comment: Saying what it **DOES** do may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second 'for' loop, i is immediately not <1, so the loop never executes.

```
for(int i =7; i<1; i--)
```

should say

```
for(int i =7; i>=0; i--)
```

Comment: looks like I need to revise my for-loops! fantastic, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```c
int ledPins[]={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};

void setup()
{
  for (int i =0; i <11; i++)
  {
    pinMode(ledPins[i],OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  for(int i =0; i<11; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],HIGH);
    delay(30);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],LOW);
  }

  for(int i =10; i>1; i--)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],HIGH);
    delay(80);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: I cleaned up your code a bit. In addition to that, when the OP asks for an explanation why he was wrong, it's at the very least a bit... odd, to answer with just code, and no explanation whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

(a) I'm not 100% familiar with what your language demands but, are your "for" tests of the form (start, while, action) or (start, until, action) ?

If the latter then your "<8" tests should be  be ">7"

If tests are start/while then OK as is.

(b) In the second LED lighting loop (the downcount)  LOW and HIGH should be swapped - going backwards does not change the way you want the LED to light.

Comment: it's (start,while,action) 

and yeah the 2nd loop's LOW and HIGH were the wrong way round, I've swapped them (edited the question too) but the for loop still isn't working

Comment: ahh swapping the for-loops for while loops makes it work. I should have tried this first. Grr! Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Count-down loops are more traditionally done with pre-decrement:

```
for(i=8; i>0; --i)
{
  ...
}
```

Would count from 7 to 0.  The --i decreases i by 1 as the very first thing that gets done after the comparison.

Comment: for loops in C are entirely equivalent to "expression1; while( expression2 != 0 ){ loop-body-code; expression3 }".  I.e., the final expression (whether it's pre- or post- increment or decrement, or something else, is the last thing done after executing the loop-body code.  So your expression would execute for values of i of [8,7,...,1].  In this context, --i and i-- are equivalent and you can choose one or the other to aid readability.  I usually write standalone increment or decrement expressions as pre-(whichevers) because they read the way I say them, e.g., "decrement i".

Comment: ... One of many references: http://cprogramminglanguage.net/c-for-loop-statement.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code for an ATmega32 microcontroller and tried to not use any `if` or `for` loops, so I used three `while` loops and mathematical shift right and left for doing this "Cylon Eye" program.

Here is the code, I hope it might be helpful:

```
#include <mega32.h>
#include <delay.h>
#define  sleep delay_ms(500)
 
// Declare your global variables here
unsigned char x;
void main(void)
{

DDRA = 0xFF;
PORTA = 0x00;

while (1)     
      {
       int i=0;
       x = 1; 
       while(i<7)
          {
           PORTA = x; 
           sleep;
           x=x*2;  
           i = i+1;
          } 
       x = 128; 
       //while(7<i<14) it makes a while trap!!
       while(i<14)  //working Nice and without any Error
          {
           PORTA = x; 
           sleep;
           x=x/2;  
           i = i+1; 
          }  
       i=0;      
      }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Commented example code:

```
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin 13 to 10 as an output.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(50);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(50);             // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(50);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(50); 
  digitalWrite(11, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(50);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(11, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(50);             // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(50);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(11, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(50);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(11, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(50);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(50); 
   digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(50);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: rule of thumb: if you have that many lines in your program that look almost the same, there is most likely room for improvement :)